# 0xC4 Blue Screen with HyperSLI and Virtual Box

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I wonder if anyone had any insight as to why my Windows 7 install blue screens whenever I start VirtualBox VMs while HyperSLI is enabled.  I know that HyperSLI is the issue, because if I restart the computer and disable it, or remember to disable it beforehand, the computer doesn't blue screen.  This started happening as recently as VirtualBox 4.1.8.  Prior to that version, I would get thrown an error saying that a certain BIOS parameter (AMD-V or VT-x) is not enabled.  Before 4.1.8, the virtual machine would run just fine and I couldn't seem to notice any issues at all.  What did VirtualBox change?  The error code was much friendlier than the blue screen halting all of my work.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Bug Check 0xC4: DRIVER_VERIFIER_DETECTED_VIOLATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560187.aspx).

Well, something is quite obviously starting Driver Verifier, a tool for us kernel/driver developers to check the sanity of our drivers. And since you can pinpoint it already to a component (HyperSLI), the best would be to disable that component or "unconfigure" Driver Verifier from verifying that driver (may have to be done in a scheduled task in case that component is enabling it again and again).

First, use (in an elevated prompt):

```
verifier /query
```

to find which driver is being verified. This should yield a result other than `No drivers are currently verified`. If you get `No drivers are currently verified` something is wrong in kernel space on your computer and I'd suggest a malware scan as the next measure. If you find the culprit driver, though, use (still from an elevated prompt):

```
verifier /reset
```

and reboot the machine to turn off Driver Verifier entirely. Remember that the HyperSLI might be re-enabling it, so short of removing it, you'll have to run this on every startup *after* HyperSLI does (*in case it does*).

Comment: When running verifier /query it does print `No drivers are currently verified`.  I know my machine doesn't have malware because currently that is part of my job, removing malware from customers computers.  When I reread the top part of the HyperSLI forum thread it said that when enabled it stops AMD-V from showing up.  Could it be that because I had it enabled in VirtualBox originally, but then my motherboard is showing it as disabled VirtualBox is having issues?

Comment: I'm in the antimalware-industry, too. So I would always doubt myself claiming a system is clean, when you can't really prove that. Either way usually when you need to enable AMD-V in the BIOS, access to the BIOS is required to disable it. Can you give the output from `!analyze -v` (from the Minidump of that crash) in your question, please?! Any driver can bug-check with arbitrary codes as long as the bug-check is deliberate. However, this reserved bug-check should normally only be seen with Driver Verifier. Need the call stack.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KSqnT4Dm Here is a pastebin of the `!analyze -v` output.

Comment: @tlunter: could you run `.symfix; .reload` on the WinDbg command prompt and then run `!analyze -v` once again after that and post the new output? Basically the symbols are missing, so we have no call stack :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vh2WrPwt  That is the output when running .symfix; .reload .  The analyze output is the same from there on.

Comment: @tlunter: we're not getting any further here. Did you run this on a different system than the system that crashes?

Comment: I haven't ran it on any other computers because I don't have any other computer that has the same setup.  Most of my computers run a Linux derivative.  This one is Windows so I can play games and just happens to be beefy enough to virtualize small Linux systems as well.  I tried seeing if it was a difference in the windbg x86 vs x64 versions, which it doesn't seem changed anything.  Is there any other method I should be checking?  I have a feeling that this is a problem just due to HyperSLIs incompleteness that I'll just have to live with for a bit.

Comment: @tlunter: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas for the moment, sorry :-|